# What are these windshield washer parts called, and what should I replace?

Tags: windshield-washer

My windshield washer doesn't work very well, there is almost no pressure when the fluid comes out. As you can see in the photo below, there is a section of clear tube which I added a while back due to a rupture in the original black tube.

Now there seems to be another rupture in a different spot on the black tube so I plan on just replacing it (the black tube is #1 in the photo).

My question is, do I need to replace #2 and/or #3 in order to replace #1? What are these parts called so I can ask for them?

I don't think it matters, but this is on a 2003 Infiniti g35.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The parts are called:**

#1 Windshield washer arm hose (the only name that makes sense, there isn't really a standard name for it besides windshield washer hose which confuses it with other hoses of that system)

#2 Windshield washer hose connector / nipple (some may call it nozzle but that confuses it with the end part that actually sprays)

#3 Windshield washer arm

**Replacement:**

It is not necessary to replace the arm (#3) or the nipple connector (#2) in order to replace the arm hose. It is quite easy to disconnect the arm hose (#1) from the other parts and find a replacement. In my search for a replacement hose car part stores tell me to go to the dealership, but it seems I can just get a similarly-sized hose from a home hardware store and fit it.

Answer (score 5):

I can't tell from the photo but the washer system only contains a few parts. With the hose disconnected turn on the wash cycle. If fluid squirts from the hose the pump is working. If any of the hoses leak then  repair or place them. The final part is the nozzle. This is the part that actually  forms the spray pattern .Depending on the make and model you may be able to clean them if they are plugged. Using a very small piece of wire try to push any debris out of the nozzle. If cleaning doesn't help they will need to be replaced. Some vehicles can use a universal replacement nozzle others require an original replacement.

Comment: Thanks, that info is related and helpful but didn't really answer my question.